# error: package generated.schema does not exist

Tags: java, android, javapoet, annotation-processor

In my Android Application I have an annotation processor which generates files using `JavaPoet` and places them under the package generated.schema.

The files are generating correctly. Whenever I use the generated file like so

```
GeneratedFile.someGeneratedMethod();
```

I get the following error:

```
error: package generated.schema does not exist.
```

But if I include the fully qualified class name instead of importing like so

```
generated.schema.GeneratedFile.someGeneratedMethod();
```

the code compiles and runs without any error.

I don't want to add complete package each time I am using `GeneratedFile`. I'm not sure what I did wrong, since I'm still learning to work with **Annotation Processor**.

Files generated by other libraries including Realm, DataBinding are all working correctly as expected.

**File Generation :**

using JavaPoet I run the following code.

```
if (roundEnvironment.processingOver()) {
    for (TypeElement element : apiList) {
        TypeSpec clazz = generateFile(element);

        JavaFile.builder(NamespaceCreator.generateClassPackage(element), clazz)
                .build()
                .writeTo(filer);
    }
}
```

- `NamespaceCreator.generateClassPackage(element)` returns the package name for `class` i.e `generated.schema`.

Comment: how do you write the file inside your processor?

Comment: @ElHoss I'm using JavaPoet, I've added the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating classes I was waiting for the last processing pass. the code generation encapsulated by

```
if (roundEnvironment.processingOver())
```

I was getting a warning because of this:

> **File for type 'generated.schema.GeneratedFile' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.**

I was aware of this warning before I posted the question, however I was willing to ignore further annotation processing on my generated files for simplicity of generating all files in one go.

Even though, after removing the last round/pass check from file generation I can correctly (with import) access the generated files without any error; I still don't understand how generating files throughout all rounds affects accessing files during build with `import`.

For that I will be posting a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831539/annotationprocessing-generating-files-at-each-round-vs-at-last-round).