# AnnotationProcessing - Generating Files at Each Round vs at Last Round

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet

I was playing around with annotation processing and was unable to use generated files directly via an import in my code. Instead I had to prepend the generated class with its complete package. I posted a SO question [error: package generated.schema does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698084/error-package-generated-schema-does-not-exist).

In the end I figured out the reason for this, turned out to be pretty simple, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831465/1889768) to the same post. Turned out the error was because I was generating the files at last round of processing, instead of anywhere in between.

**So my questions are:**

- How does generating files at last round vs generating files at in between rounds changes accessing the generated files in code?
- Is there a specific reason (Java-related or otherwise) for this behavior?

Comment: Does you generate source code contain annotation which needs another APT?

Comment: @ElHoss No.....